# What to respond with so that a narrator understands that you are following him?

Tags: subcontinental-english

In the following video,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wHh7cDQi48

we see that the listener is responding by saying "**Okay**" periodically. But, I don't think, this is the standard form of expression.

What to respond with so that a narrator understands that you are following him?

Answer (score 2):

The usage is just fine:

***[OK](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ok#OK_Interjection_100)***

> used to express assent, agreement, or acceptance.

-- Oxford

By saying *OK* the listener is acknowledging they agree or accept what has been said, which by definition implies they understand it.

Another idiomatic expression you could use is:

***[I see](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+see)***

> also, I see what you mean. I understand...

-- Farlex, Idioms.

If you do not want to interrupt the flow of the speaker you could also use non verbal communication. For example a nod of the head, or a simple smile, can be used to demonstrate that you are following along with what the speaker is saying.

Comment: How about `mm...hm...` or `aa...ha...`?

Comment: if pause is great and  looks like narrator expects a reaction, probably one would make some question along the  described  events. "So, what happened next?" or "I'm with you so far" to express understanding?

Comment: In fact, Oxford is at least a bit off about *OK*. I say that because if not most days then at least weekly for at least 10 or 20 years I have found myself challenging people who said *OK* precisely because I think Oxford *ought to be* correct, only to find that they simply don't understand the concept.

*OK* they say, *is just an expression* - I quote, there -  *It doesn't mean I think it's alright; it's just a figure of speech…*